# Cron.php not working and no "Cron (Scheduled Tasks)" configuration block

Tags: magento-1.6, cron

I've a magento 1.6 instance that doesn't trigger cron jobs when cron.php is hit. It also doesn't have a Cron (Scheduled Tasks) configuration section under Admin > System > Configuration > System. Mage_Cron is enabled. I've no idea why it isn't working. Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in thre magento or php logs? Is the cron table in the database filled with tasks?

Comment: Nothing in the cron_schedule table and nothing in the logs. Something is amiss because the cron admin isn't even showing.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue.
One of the modules installed on the site was disabling the cron system in it's config file:

<config><modules><Mage_Cron><active>false</active></Mage_Cron></modules></config>